# Is it possible that $]0,1[$ homeomorphic to $[a,b]$?

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible that $]0,1[$ homeomorphic to $[a,b]$ ? I know that $]0,1[$ is open in $\mathbb R$ and $[a,b]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, but since in $[a,b]$ is open with the topology of subspace, maybe it has sens to say that $[a,b]$ and $]0,1[$ are homeomorphic when $[a,b]$ is not considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$ but as a topology space (with the topology induced). What do you think ?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What notation is invalid?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That notation is **not** invalid. "$]a, b[$" is indeed used for the open interval $(a, b)$ in many texts, it's perfectly valid (although I strongly prefer the other notation). See e.g. the second sentence of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OpenInterval.html).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck AFAIK $]a,b[$ is a standard notation in France, and probably in some other places too. This is a valid notation, just the one which isn't standard in English-speaking countries.

Comment: it is possible depending on how you define stuff

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Lighten up. Different places have different notations. Who's to say *we're* not the one's who use the wrong notation? Indeed, if I recall correctly "$]\cdot, \cdot[$" was introduced because it more naturally describes an open interval, showing the endpoints "pushed off to the sides". I don't use it, but I think there's no reason to look down on it.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That's a price we pay for having a rich history of mathematics, and a tendency to not give up traditions. They might've been introduced at different geographical locations independently one another.

Comment: @Noah: I’m not quite that generous: I think that it’s visually confusing and typographically rather appalling, but unfortunately it is, as you say, one of the accepted standards. (And while I dislike it, it doesn’t annoy me *nearly* as much as the idiocy of using $T_3$ to mean *regular* and vice versa despite the obvious hierarchy implicit in the $T_k$ notation.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that your arguments do not show that the intervals are non-homeomorphic. However, one is compact, and the other is not, so they cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree for the argument of compactness. What about $(0,1)$ and $(a,b]$ ? (since $(a,b]$ is not compact, it may can work, no ?)

Comment: @user352653 For that one, the *connectedness* argument works; see Wojowu's answer. Another argument that works is that $(a, b]$ is the union of a connected set and a connected compact nonempty set (namely, $(a, b]=(a, b)\cup [{a+b\over 2}, b]$), while $(a, b)$ is not.

Comment: @user352653 In that case, the other answers work better.

Comment: @user352653 Another fun answer: $[a, b)$ has a continuous bijection onto the unit circle ("glue $a$ to $b$"), while $(a, b)$ does not. (Note that a continuous bijection is **not** the same as a homeomorphism! The circle and $[a, b)$ are not homeomorphic.)

Comment: @user352653 Finally, here's a really silly answer: via the notion of [ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_(topology)). We can show that $[a, b)$ has one end, while $(a, b)$ has two, and hence they are not homeomorphic. However, developing the properties of ends requires arguments about connectedness, and essentially subsumes the "remove-a-point" argument, so this shouldn't be taken seriously. Still, it's neat to observe that the idea that "$(a, b)$ has two endpoints missing, while $[a, b)$ is only missing one" can be made rigorous.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an argument using connectedness instead of compactness: from $[a,b]$ we can remove a point so that the resulting space is connected. The same is not true for $]0,1[$.

Comment: Dangit, beat me by 17 seconds! :P +1.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Three essentially the same answers in 20 seconds! Is that a record?

Comment: I've seen it happen before, but yeah it's unusual.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove any point from $]0,1[$ it becomes dissconected. But if you remove $a$ or $b$ from $[a,b]$ it stays connected.

It is trivial to us this to show that they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Nice, I see :-)